# Spring boot can't connect to mysql in docker for the same network

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker

**Running mysql image [latest mysql version]** [Not duplicate of this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68894130/cant-connect-spring-boot-with-mysql):

```
 docker run -d --name=docker-mysql --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test123" --env="MYSQL_USER=user1"  --env="MYSQL_PASSWORD=test123" --env="MYSQL_DATABASE=dockertest" -p 3306:3306 mysql
```

Running Spring boot app image:

```
docker run -t -p 8080:8080 --link docker-mysql:mysql docker-userapp
```

note:

1. when I run spring boot with mysql in local enviroment with these credential, project works fine
2. MySQL container I am running above works fine as I can log in to the containerized MySQL server and run command manually.

It seems, MySQL container is ok, but somehow, spring boot can't access the database. I am new in docker. Please suggest what do I need to change?

spring **application.properties** file:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
server.servlet.contextPath=/docker-api
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dockertest
spring.datasource.username=user1
spring.datasource.password=test123

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Error log:

> 2021-12-06 12:46:18.386  INFO 1 --- [           main]
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
> 2021-12-06 12:46:18.389  WARN 1 --- [           main]
> com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with
> driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was not found, trying direct
> instantiation. 2021-12-06 12:46:19.505 ERROR 1 --- [           main]
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception
> during pool initialization.
>
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications
> link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
> ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.     at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]   at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]   at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]   at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:448)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]   at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]   at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]   at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
> ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]    at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
> ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]    at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
> ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]    at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
> [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]     at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
> [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]     at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115)
> [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]     at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
> [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]     at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
> [hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]    at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181)
> [hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]    at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
> [hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]    at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
> [hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]

Comment: This question is heavily related to docker, I would suggest adding "docker" into the title.

Comment: see if this helps  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276117/5193536

Comment: Mysql and your app are in same network right? You can also access mysql with docker name  like "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/dockertest" If you defined your mysql as 'mysql' in your docker compose

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez, yes they are on the same network, thanks for your suggestion. will try that

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you dont have the driver dependency as part of the libs of your APP.jar which is running on docker.

As a start, look into your `/target/app.jar`, unzip this jar and see if it is a FAT jar, meaning it has all the required dependencies there.

See if you can find the jar `mysql-connector-java` there, that is what you are missing.

Maven:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java

Comment: I can that jar in `/BOOT-INF/lib/` path.